# How to reorder MongoDB keys?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have been trying to query for students with GPA>=90 from different "year" values using:

```
aggregate( { $unwind: '$students'},{ $match: {'students.GPA': {$gte: 90}}}
,{ $group: {_id:'$year',
     students: {$push: {id:'$students.id',firstName:'$students.firstName',
lastName:'$students.lastName',
      GPA:'$students.GPA',}}}},{$project : {
        _id : 0 ,
        year : '$_id' ,
        students : 1
    }},{$sort:{year:1}})
```

Which returns a correct and wanted result of:

```
{
students: [
{
   id: 1,
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Doe",
   GPA: 91
}
  ],
  year: 2012
}
```

The only thing is that In the original document the field "year" comes before the array "students".
I know that Mongo can rearrange fields order, is there a way to avoid it or manually order them?

This query was a workaround as the following one gave me a error:

> "exception: the group aggregate field 'year' must be defined as an
>   expression inside an object"

```
aggregate( { $unwind: '$students'},{ $match: {'students.GPA': {$gte: 90}}}, 
{$project : {
        _id : 0 ,
        year : 1 ,
        students : 1
    }},{ $group: {_id:0,year:'$year',
     students: {$push: {id:'$students.id',firstName:'$students.firstName',
        lastName:'$students.lastName',
      GPA:'$students.GPA',}}}})
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does the order matter? It's a hash, order of its keys should not be important to your logic.

Comment: it's not super important i just wanted to explore the option of doing so

Comment: @JohnnyHK works perfectly by adding _ before the field name in the projection according to the link you provided. Thanks a lot